# Can I obtain the boundedness of a function from the boundedness of its integration

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

Assume for some finite positive constants $\tau,C$ and $\lambda$, the positive function $f$ satisfies
$$\int_0^\tau f(t,s,x)ds\leq C \exp (-\lambda t),$$
where the constants are independent of $t$.

What kind of condition do we need on the function $f$ to obtain the following result?
$$f(t,s,x)\leq C \exp (-\lambda t),$$
where $C$ is independent of time $t$.
Is it enough that we just assume the function $f$ is continuous w.r.t $s$ in the interval [$0$,$\tau$]

Answer (score 2):

Bounds on the integral of a function do not give bounds on the function itself. To illustrate this, let's ignore the variables $t$ and $x$ for now and just consider functions $f(s)$ on the interval $[0,1].$

For example the functions $f_\epsilon\colon[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f_\epsilon(s)=(s+\epsilon)^{-{1/2}}$ (for say $\epsilon < 1$) have a uniform integral bound:
$$
 \int_0^1 f_\epsilon(s) d s=\int_\epsilon^{1+\epsilon}r^{-1/2}dr=(1+\epsilon)^{1/2}-\epsilon^{1/2}\le3
$$
However, $\sup_{s\in[0,1]}f_\epsilon(s)=\epsilon^{-1/2}\rightarrow \infty$ for $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But if we assume the continuity of function $f$ on $s$. Can we obtain the result as we have the extreme value theorem?

Comment: Well, the functions $f_\epsilon$ *are* continuous on $[0,1]$. Even more, they are smooth up to the boundary, it doesn't get much better.

Comment: If $f(\epsilon,s)$ is continuous on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ then it is automatically bounded, without any integration argument being necessary. Here continuity in _both_ variables is necessary.

Comment: Hence the continuity on $s$ would be necessary condition for boundedness. Would the integration help for the exponential contraction?